# Custom URI using javascript

Tags: javascript, mod-rewrite

I encountered a e-commerce website which does the following whenever a filter is applied on the product list page:

For example when you click a "subcategory = 2" (link with href="/productcategory/category1/subcategory2") on the product list page "www.example.com/productcategory/category1"

1. URI that is displayed in the address bar is changed to mimic the filter request without reloading the entire page. i.e. "www.example.com/productcategory/category1/subcategory2"
2. An ajax call reloads only a part of the page according to the filter applied i.e. product with subcategory = 2 are displayed.

But also when you enter  "www.example.com/productcategory/category1/subcategory2" in the address bar a new page is reloaded as usual.

I am not able to achieve this particular behavior using rewrite rule because whenever I click on a link with href="www.example.com/productcategory/category1/subcategory2" it is redirected according to the rewrite rule and a entire new page is reloaded.

My question:
1. how is it possible to change the URL in address bar but not reload the page? 
2. Is it possible to have a rewrite rule which only redirects a page only when you explicitly enter the url in the address bar and hit enter?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To update the url displayed by the browser, without reloading the page, you can use the [JavaScript History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) - examples [here](http://html5doctor.com/demos/history/).

I'm not clear what you mean by the second part of your question, rewrite rules get applied when a request is received by the web server - the server doesn't know/care about how the request was triggered, but if you are using the History API to update the url in the browser then no requests get sent to the server, this is purely an in-browser operation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. pushState() is the function I was looking for.